# Design concept to prevent duplicate orders being received into my system

Tags: php, duplicates, mutex, phalcon

I have a web system that I built that is an online ordering portal for our customers. We store their stock and they place orders for it through this portal.

We do a duplication check on the customer reference number so that the same order cannot come through twice, however we have been experiencing some issues whereby if a customer sends the order to our API multiple times (within milliseconds, if that, of eachother), our system doesn't have enough time to mark the order as received and as such, the system is allowing duplicates.

I am trying to decide on ways to combat this. I don't want to use database constraints for this as I find this an application issue rather than a database issue and don't believe this is a good solution.

Any design ideas on how to combat this? One solution I thought of was to use a mutex with the reference number so that if a mutex is locked for that reference number, then it might retry in a second etc? My understanding is that Mutex's are almost fool proof as they are enforced by the filesystem?

Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: If you have access to the button they click in the app, introduce a time based disable on the submit button (3-5 seconds should be ok), unless there is a valid reason for the customer to send the same request multiple times in 1-2 seconds

Comment: Thanks but the orders come from an API call so this is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

You could try employing a nonce strategy. The idea is to set random number to a hidden form field and store it in the session. Verify the id on post. The user has to deliberately refresh the page to obtain a new id and be able to post a second time.

## update

So since you are using API service, then I would have to say you could use a batch system. Where an order comes in and gets stored in a holding area. A chron job runs through the batch and does the necessary pruning operations.

Comment: The orders get posted through an API call so this won't work.